# message with array of different messages

Tags: ros, custom-message, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

in my code i define something like

```
class Sphere { ...
class Plane { ...
...
```

and defined a vector with different shape types.

Now i want to send this information as ROS message. Is it possible that i can define a message like

```
 shapes[] shapes
```

and shape could be plane or sphere?

Thank you for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62769/message-with-array-of-different-messages/) by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 222 on 2013-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Simple answer: No

Longer answer: You could make a shape message that contains every possible shape. An example would be [visualization_msgs/Marker](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/Marker.html) that puts multiple shapes in one message.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-05-15**:
ok thank you, that was my first idea too.